# web scraping with selenium returning multiple web domains

Tags: python, selenium

I need to perform multiple queries on this site and return the status of making an offer or buying to me, however my code returns an unexpected value https://instantdomainsearch.com/en/#search=gmail.com but my code cannot insert the other link , any idea how to solve this problem?

```
domains = ['gmail.com','hotmail']
#scrape elements
ff = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="D:/Programas/gecko/geckodriver.exe")

for domain in domains:
    ff.get('https://instantdomainsearch.com/pt/#search='+str(domains))
    html = ff.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    list_ = soup.find('div', {'class':'awrzayw'})
    elements = list_.find('a')

    try:
       elements = list_.find('a')
    except:
       elements = "comprar"

    for element in elements:
       print(element)
```

[image]

Comment: `domains` is a list. When you say `str(domains)` you are converting the `list` to a `string`. use `str(domain)` Note the slight difference in `for domain in domains` and `str(domains)` vs `str(domain)`. On a further note, since it is already a string, you don't even have to convert it. You can just use `domain`

Comment: I couldn't understand it could be more specific in the exit code. I replaced str with format and the error persists. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs on this line. You were initially calling domains. You are iterating over domains so use the individual element.

```
ff.get('https://instantdomainsearch.com/pt/#search='+str(domains))
```

---

```
domains = ['gmail.com','hotmail']
#scrape elements
ff = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="D:/Programas/gecko/geckodriver.exe")

for domain in domains:
    ff.get('https://instantdomainsearch.com/pt/#search='+ domain)
    html = ff.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    list_ = soup.find('div', {'class':'awrzayw'})
    elements = list_.find('a')

    try:
       elements = list_.find('a')
    except:
       elements = "comprar"

    for element in elements:
       print(element)
```

Comment: The problem now is that he is stuck only in the first domain and I need him to return the different values and not repeat them.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: The problem now is that he is stuck only in the first domain and I need him to return the different values and not repeat them.

Comment: But you are looping over `domains`. So first it will search for `gmail.com`, then it will search for `hotmail`. I am still confused by your request.